# Sqlite database doesn't update the data from web services

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing an app which gets JSON datas from the web service and update it in the SQLite database. My problem is i got the values from web services but while uploading it shows 'null'. its not getting updated.

my code:-

```
-(void) updateSignupTable: (NSDictionary*) json {
    //copying the values from web services

    NSString *balance =  [json objectForKey:@"balance"];
    NSString *phone_number =[json objectForKey:@"sim_number"];
    NSString *call_forward_Status = [json objectForKey:@"call_forward_status"];
```

//Storing it in the database

```
    sqlExecutObj.sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE profile_table SET phone_number ='%@' balance = '%@' call_forward_status = '%@' WHERE profile_name= '%@'", phone_number ,balance, call_forward_Status, profileDetailTitle];

    sqlExecutObj.dataTypeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",nil];

    [sqlExecutObj executeSelectQuery];
///reloading the table    
    [profileDetailView.detailsTableView reloadData];

    // fetch and print the  updated datas from SQLite

    sqlExecutObj.sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT call_forward_status,phone_number,balance FROM profile_table WHERE profile_name= '%@'",selectedProfileName];

    sqlExecutObj.dataTypeArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"1",@"1",nil];

    [sqlExecutObj executeSelectQuery];

    NSLog(@"result from table are: %@. and  %@, and %@", [[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0],[[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0],[[sqlExecutObj.result objectAtIndex:2]objectAtIndex:0] );
}
```

My debug output:-

```
2013-05-14 15:54:02.910 Movirtu[44262:19d03] result from table are: (null). and  (null), and (null)
```

Comment: What is `sqlExecuteObj`?  Why are you using `executeSelectQuery` to perform an `UPDATE`?

Comment: sqlExecute.obj is an variable for class SQLite which i have it in SQLite.h and executeQuery is an method to perform the query which sqlExecuteobj.sql holds.

Comment: i used the same procedure to store any static variable in different places of my code, it works, but hear its not working.

Comment: Perhaps it's broken then?

Comment: broken? how can i get rid of this.

Comment: By fixing it.  We cannot help, however, until you show us its implementation.

Comment: thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be cautious, the following line:

```
 sqlExecutObj.sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE profile_table SET phone_number ='%@' balance = '%@' call_forward_status = '%@' WHERE profile_name= '%@'", phone_number ,balance, call_forward_Status, profileDetailTitle];
```

Specifies 'profileDetailTitle as the profile_name, but the second statement, where you're reading the data from the database:

```
sqlExecutObj.sql=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT call_forward_status,phone_number,balance FROM profile_table WHERE profile_name= '%@'",selectedProfileName];
```

Specifies that the profile_name is 'selectedProfileName'.

In your code, it's not obvious what either profileDetailTitle, or selectedProfileName is.  Perhaps for the sake of debugging, you set them both to the same value.

Also, just to be sure, if either the profileDetailTitle or selectedProfileName is user-driven, or maybe just contains non-alphanumeric characters, you should be (either) binding, sanity checks, escaping those values. The same goes for any other values being input into the database - but this is not to scope ;-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.Actually i did many code checks by changing the variable names and that is the reason behind that.But both the 'selectedProfileNAme' and 'ProfileDEtailTitle' holds the same value.